# AngularJS - Show the array values on front end

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm pushing values to an array that came from a select box to accomplish that, I'm doing this:

```js
$scope.selectedValues = [{

}]

$scope.print = function() {
  $scope.selectedValues.push($scope.model);
}
```

```html
<div>{{selectedValues}}</div>
```

What I see in my front end is the array whit the values `[{},"01","02"]` and not the values only.
I need to present only the values.

Comment: initialise it as `$scope.selectedValues = []`

Comment: display it as `<div>{{selectedValues.join(" ")}}</div>`

Comment: Thank you all !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript

```
$scope.selectedValues = [];

$scope.print = function() {
  $scope.selectedValues.push($scope.model);
};
```

Markup

```
<div>
  <span ng-repeat="value in selectedValues">{{value}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have pushing empty object into **selectedValues {}**.
array should be declared like this

```
$scope.selectedValues = [];
```

Comment: Sammer , Thank you.